# Vue3 highlight text in a textarea avec it gets enabled

Tags: vuejs3

I have a textarea with some text in it. I have some logic that makes it so the user can highlight part of the text and change it with the result of an API call. While the frontend is waiting for the response, I want to have the textarea disabled. When I receive the result, I want to enable it again, update the portion of the text the user want to change and highlight a portion of the text.

So basically :

1. hightlight
2. click for change request
3. textarea disabled
4. request sent
5. result received
6. textarea value udpdated
7. textarea enabled
8. new text portion highlighted

My issue is that it works perfectly fine is I skip the steps 3 (disable) and 7 (enable), but if I do those then the text is not highlighted. Why do I get this behaviour and how can I get the portion of the text highlighted properly after I enable the textarea?

Here's the code :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea
      ref="editor"
      :disabled="generating" />
  </div>
  <button@click="regenerate">Regenerate selected text</button>
</template>

<script setup>
  const selectionStart = 10;
  const editor = ref(null);
  const generating = ref(false);

  const regenerate = () => {
    generating.value = true; // Here is what I need to comment for the result to be highlited properly
    const selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    const response = await $fetch( [ ...request  ] );

    const originalText = editor.value.value;
    let newText = originalText.replace(selection, response);
    editor.value.value = newText;

    generating.value = false; // Here is what I need to comment for the result to be highlited properly
    editor.value.selectionStart = 10;
    editor.value.selectionEnd = 10 + response.length;
  }
</script>
```